# How to compare values like N/A in json

Tags: java, arrays, json, cucumber-serenity

Comparing lists using java

I have a dropdown consist of
[Black, N/A, Neutrals, Novelty, Solid Seasonal Colour, White]

I have a json file which have above values in it

```
{
        "Colour Bucket": {
            "codeSet1": "Black",
            "codeSet2": "N/A",
            "codeSet2": "Neutrals",
            "codeSet3": "Novelty",
            "codeSet4": "Solid Seasonal Colour",
            "codeSet5": "White"
        }
    },
```

When i tried to compare both lists getting exception because N/A is converted as N/A in runtime.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: What is the type of `codeSet2`? Is it an enum? If so, can you show its definition?

Comment: Its a value like N/A which means not available, in run time N/A is changing to N\/A

Comment: Well, the JSON does not show that the value "N/A" is any different than the other values. So you need to provide your Java code which unmarshalls this JSON.

Comment: Some JSON frameworks escape each `/`. That makes the value _look like_ `N\/A` to us people, but when the JSON is parsed the value will become `N/A` again.

Comment: is it possible to parse N/A value separately.

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?

Comment: JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(path + "/src/test/resources/TestData/" + jsonFileName + ".json")) {
// Read JSON file
Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONArray codesetList = (JSONArray) obj;
// Iterate over the array
for (int i = 0; i < codesetList.size(); i++) {
if (codesetList.get(i).toString().contains(expectedJsonArrayName)) {
list = parseJsonObject((JSONObject) codesetList.get(i), expectedJsonArrayName);
}
}
return list;
}

Comment: actuallist = enbDashboardPage.findElementsTextForCodesetDropdownValues(actualValue);
    expectedlist = jsonreader.readJsonFileData(actualValue, JsonFileName);

    if (expectedlist.equals(actuallist)) {
     Assert.assertEquals(expectedlist, actuallist,
       "Both are equal. " + "Expected List: " + expectedlist + "And Actual List: " + actuallist);
    } else {
     Assert.assertEquals(expectedlist, actuallist, "Both are NOT equal. " + "Expected List: "
       + expectedlist + "But Actual List: " + actuallist);
    }

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Trying to compare N/A value with json and UI, but json is adding esc(\) character in the runtime.
like N\/A